# If only dicots have pith, what is the foam in the middle of cornstalks?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

I've heard that the only plants that have pith are dicots, because of the shape of their vascular bundle. If that is true, what is the foam inside of the corn plants, which are monocots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monocots [do have pith](http://users.rcn.com/jkimball.ma.ultranet/BiologyPages/S/Stems.html) in their stems. The link even has an image of a maize stem:

[image: Maize stem]